# How can I fix the 'failed to load session cinnamon' error in Debian after updating Python?

Tags: debian, tty, gpg-signature, cinnamon, failed-to-load-viewstate

access to my user session on debian "failed to load session cinnamon"

Hi people, I was traied to update my python version using some commands that I'd found on google. When I tried to login to my session again, it print a message with "failed to load session cinnamon". I've searched a lot of answers for this problem but I did not get success. I tried to execute:

1 - restart - failed

2 - type follow commands on tty (it also failed):
2.1 - sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
2.2 - sudo apt install cinnamon.

After trying to install cinnamon, it responses to me some curious messages:
"Follow signatures could not be checked besides public key is unavaiable: NO_PUBKEY 7FCC77D46ACCC4CF8"
"The repository http://www.rabbitmq.com/debian testing Release does not have a Release file"
"An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bullseye-pgdg InRelease: The signatures......"

Although I do not beleave it could be the problem, can someone help me with it?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: I forgot to comments that, after installed cinnamon, I'd reboot and the same problem persists.

Comment: People please! I need help!